# How do multipliers work in Temple Run?

Tags: ios, temple-run

In Temple Run, after the run, you see your current multiplier. Collecting objectives also gives you multipliers, but how do they work? When I get an objective that says multiplier 24x (or any other number), it doesn't feel like I get 24 times as many points. How does this work?

Comment: Distance xmultiplier + (coins x 5 x multiplier) = score Jk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to find out *approximately* what your score might be:

If you were to run a certain distance without getting any coins your score (`S`) would equal your distance (`d`) times your multiplier (`m`): `S = m × d`.

But when you add coins, your score is the multiplier times the distance times the amount of coins (`c`) divided by 1000: `S = m × d × c / 1000`.

(This may be off by 1000 points.)

Comment: thx. Mine is around 4,800,000, which concidering me being visually impaired is not bad.

Comment: All your so-called formulas are totally not working or even close. My scores: multiplier 39x, 114 coins, 684 meters for a score of 72306. Somebody figure that out, please.

Comment: Hey Kevin, I think my answer covers your case. Check it out :)

Comment: The formula does not seem right (not even approximately). Keeping the distance and the multiplier constant, I would get a better score by NOT collecting coins instead of collecting coins.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing to a correct answer I can see is what Ibkid says -
(`distance` + (`coins` * 5)) * `multiplier` = `Final Score`

However this seems to apply **only if you never filled the coin meter**. When you fill the coin meter, you get some bonus points for getting a coin part, these are 100 and 250 points for the first and second part respectively and 500 for each part afterwards, additionally, each time you get a coin part it seems you get another bonus 500 points. 
Tripping or dying and using ressurection empties the meter and resets the coin parts.

I've made some tests myself and I think the final formula is this:
(`distance` + (`times filled meter` * 500) + (`coins` * 5) + `coin part bonuses`) * `multiplier` = `Final Score`

For example, if I have a x25 multiplier, ran 1000 meters and collected 250 coins without tripping/ressurecting, I'll get (1000 + 2*500 + 250*5 + (100 + 250)) * 25 = 90,000 points

It seems that there are other factors which affect this score, I think coins collected by bonuses like with magnet or by collecting a mega coin have different values, because of the nature of these bonuses, it's hard for me to test the exact values.

Answer (score 2):

Multipliers are definitely increasing your score over time.  Watch this video:

You'll see that at the beginning, the score you gain per second is something like 150 points.  When the player gets to 7000 and then at 10000 points (and they're not collecting coins) you can watch the hundreds digit spin faster and faster as the multiplier climbs.  I'm not 100% convinced that it's being honest about the multiplier's mathematical effect, but it's definitely making a difference.

Comment: What app did you use to record your screen?

Comment: @jeremy, this is not my video, I'm only linking to it from youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Distance = D
Coins = C
Multiplier = M
Score = S

All you do is: ( M x D ) + ( C x M x 2 ) = S

So lets say D = 100, C = 50 and M = 25.

Your score is (25 x 100) + (50 x 25 x 2) which equals 5000.

Answer (score 0):

It is the distance (**d**) times the multiplier (**m**) plus coins (**c**) times multiplier times 5, so  `md + 5mc = score`.

Also, the game needs to factor in power-ups increasing coin value after a certain distance.

Comment: I am mistaken. Instead of coins times 125 it's coins times 5xmultiplier

Comment: Can you edit that into your answer then?

Comment: There is also the factor of power ups increasing coin values that need to be factored. Trust the game for what they do, they have plenty of math geeks that worked on this

Comment: I rarely downvote an answer, but I think your condescending tone deserves it

Comment: Sorry if people can be idiots. Like the person who thinks the multiplier increases over time during the run. You are just covering distance more quickly therefore the score goes up faster. Anyone who has a small brain should be able to figure that out